# How can I reduce this Javascript/HTML/jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have hundreds, maybe thousands of charts for stores.  The only difference is the name of the store and the product.  The HTML code is dynamically generated once/day. Even minified, it takes forever to load (at least it feels like an eternity). If I use Firebug, then loading the file does take a very, very long time to load.

The stores and products are created from a table that's generated each morning. Since each table has a title (e.g., "JohnsMarket"), the ids cannot be reduced to numbers (e.g., 'store1', 'store2').

All of the other SO solutions to repetitive code use numbered ids.

For each store/product, I have to repeat the following 3 snippets.

```
<div id="JohnsMarket_Soup" class="frmStep">
   <div id="JohnsMarket_soup_chart" ></div>
   <div class="layout">
         <div class="layout_slider-settings">
            <div class="loading" id="JohnsMarket_soup_loading"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="layout_slider"><input id="JohnsMarket_soup_slider" name="area" value="1" ></div>
         <div class="layout_slider-settings"> </div>
   </div>
</div>

if ( ui.panel.id==='JohnsMarket' )
{   
   if( typeof JohnsMarket_soup_chart_data === 'undefined' )
   {
      $('.loading_graph_msg').show(); 
      window.setTimeout(function() { JohnsMarket_soup_data=checkData( JohnsMarket_soup_data,'JohnsMarket' );
      JohnsMarket_soup_chart_data = createChart(JohnsMarket_soup_data, 'JohnsMarket_soup_chart', 'JohnsMarket Soup', 50, 7, -1); },50 );
      $('.loading_graph_msg').hide('fast');
    }
} 
});

jQuery('#JohnsMarket_soup_slider').slider({}
  $('#JohnsMarket_soup_loading').show();
   var x = this.getValue();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      JohnsMarket_soup_chart_data.replot();
      JohnsMarket_soup_chart_data.destroy();
      JohnsMarket_soup_chart_data = createChart(JohnsMarket_soup_data, 'JohnsMarket_soup_chart_data', 'JohnsMarket Soup', 5, x*7, -1);
    },20 );
  }
});
```

Comment: Ever thought about placing this load onto the serverside environment? I'd suggest you look at PHP.

Comment: Not having a web site - or perhaps PHP

Comment: The data is stored server-side and is loaded only when the user views a store & product.

The charts are presented in tabs within tabs.  Top level tabs contain the store names, the inner tabs contain the products.

How would this code be stored server-side?

Comment: PHP, and other server-side languages, are processed on the web server and then render the necessary markup to the user. You don't 'store' the DIV (or any other HTML for that matter) server side, you have the server generate the necessary data/markup to send to the client.

Answer (score 3):

I can't say I fully understand what your whole problem statement looks like, but you can drastically compress all your code into one function that is used over and over again.  This will, at least trim the size of the code down.  Since you only showed one example of the data, I can't be sure what exactly is common from one data set to the next, but I made an assumption in order to show you how it can all be procedurized.  You could collapse all the code to this:

```
function checkItem(idStr) {
    if ( ui.panel.id == idStr) {
        // generate derived names
        var soupChartDataName = idStr + "_soup_chart_data";
        var soupDataName = idStr + "_soup_data";
        var soupChartData = idStr + "_soup_chart_data";
        var soupChart = idStr + "_soup_chart";
        var soup = idStr + " Soup";
        var soupSlider = idStr + "_soup_slider";
        var soupLoading = idStr + "_soup_loading";

        if (typeof window[soupChartDataName] === 'undefined') {
            $('.loading_graph_msg').show(); 
            window.setTimeout(function() { 
                window[soupDataName] = checkData(window[soupDataName], idStr );
                window[soupChartData] = createChart(window[soupChartData], soupChart, soup, 50, 7, -1); 
            }, 50);
            $('.loading_graph_msg').hide('fast');
        }

        $("#" + soupSlider).slider({});
        $("#" + soupLoading).show();
        var x = this.getValue();
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            window[soupChartDataName].replot();
            window[soupChartDataName].destroy();
            window[soupChartDataName] = createChart(soupDataName, soupChartData, soup, 5, x*7, -1);
        }, 20);
    }
}

checkItem("JohnsMarket");
```

Then, for all the other items just call checkItem() with a different idString and no additional code.  If I didn't guess the commonality among them quite correctly, you should be able to get the idea for how you can generate all the names being used from one or two common roots.  For example, if "soup" isn't common among all the derived names, then maybe you need to pas that root into checkItem too so it can vary from one name to the next.  If this were my code, I wouldn't be using so many global variables and I'd hang them off some object in my page, but that's your choice.

Note - for global variables, we access them off the `window`object so we can use the derived variable names as indexes.

And, you could create the HTML from a string template like this:

```
function createItem(idStr) {
    var template = '<div id="xxxx_soup_chart" ></div><div class="layout"><div class="layout_slider-settings"><div class="loading" id="xxxx_soup_loading"></div></div><div class="layout_slider"><input id="xxxx_soup_slider" name="area" value="1" ></div><div class="layout_slider-settings"> </div></div>';

    var o = document.createElement("div");
    o.id = idStr + "_Soup";
    o.className = "frmStep";
    o.innerHTML = template.replace(/xxxx/g, idStr);
    document.body.append(o);    // change this to append the item wherever it's supposed to go
}

createItem("JohnsMarket");
```

Comment: That looks like it would work.  I'll give that a whack.

How would I go about generating all of the DIVs?

Comment: I added code to my answer to generate the HTML from a string template.

Answer (score 1):

Any of that data seems like it could be stored in a hash keyed on the store name, including the chart itself; the rest is just string concatenation. But I agree, I'd try to move some of that onto the server side, even if it's just to retrieve the data used to create the charts.

Comment: The data is stored server-side otherwise the HTML file would be megabytes; I should know -- that was my first approach.  That killed the browser.

I still have no idea how I can store the divs, and code server side.

Comment: Why do you have to "store" them? Can't you create them as needed?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something really obvious, but how would I go about loading a DIV or, say, the slider on demand?

Comment: That's what Ajax is for--you can send HTML back from the server.

Comment: That I'll have to think about. I use Ajax for getting/saving data,  but only once for generating HTML code.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem--it's pretty handy, especially for cases like this :) jfriend00 also has a workable solution which is more or less an example of what I was saying.

Comment: "Why do you have to "store" them? Can't you create them as needed?"  Because I'm not smart enough at this point to know how to create the DIVs on demand.  The DIVs are associated with the tabs.  At what point would I load or generate the HTML code?  Sorry if I sound utterly clueless.

Comment: You'd generate them when you need to view them. Check out the jQuery UI tab examples, one of them has a remote. (And it's not smart/not-smart, it's know/not-know :)

Comment: I'll check out the tab examples again. Thank you!